# How to fix looping inserting files (getting invisible datas) using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem, I have a module where I need to insert the image and carousel details to the storage and database. but the image not totally inserted into the database. only the file name. that module is working fine and inserting correctly to my localhost server. the problem here after I upload the project to the server and then I try to upload the carousel image it happens when I press the button and successfully insert there are files selected to the data table which is not inserted to the database. I really don't understand why the uploading function is not working properly and after the page refresh happens my script select pdf file etc etc..

To understand my statement I will demonstrate to you guys the sample output and then function.

1. the correct files that I only upload is that .png file, however, happens there are files like pdf I really don't understand where it from.

**Problem:**
[image: problem]

**Database:**

**Content Table:**

[image: content_table]

**Content Files:**

[image: content_files]

**Ajax:**

```
var carousel_data = new FormData();

$('#carousel_image').on('change',function(e){

        var files = e.target.files;

        $.each(files, function(i, file) {

            carousel_data.append('files[]', file);

        });
 });




$('#btn_carousel').on('click',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var carousel_title = $('#carousel_title').val();
    var carousel_desc = $('#carousel_desc').val();
    var carousel_url = $('#carousel_url').val();

    carousel_data.append('carousel_title', carousel_title);
    carousel_data.append('carousel_desc', carousel_desc);
    carousel_data.append('carousel_url', carousel_url);
    $.ajax({

        url:'/insert_carousel_content',
        type:'post',
        data:carousel_data,
        dataType:'JSON',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(res) {
            if(res == 'Success') {
                alert('Successfully Inserted');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Please Fill The Blank.');
            }

            location.reload();
        },
        error:function(err) {
            alert('Failed To Insert');

        }
    })

});
```

**Controller:**

```
public function insert_carousel_content(Request $request) {

    $file_upload = $request->file('files');

    $carousel_title = $request->get('carousel_title');
    $carousel_desc = $request->get('carousel_desc');
    $carousel_url = $request->get('carousel_url');

    $author = Auth::user()->id;

    $now = new DateTime();

    DB::insert('INSERT INTO audit_trail (user,page,action,when_created) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ',[
        $author,
        'Carousel',
        'Inserting',
        $now
    ]);

    if($request->hasFile('files')) {

        DB::insert('INSERT INTO content (content_author,content_title,content_desc,content_link,content_page,content_status,when_created) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ',[

        $author,
        $carousel_title,
        $carousel_desc,
        $carousel_url,
        'carousel',
        'Approved',
        $now

        ]);




        $last_id_insert = DB::select('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as id FROM content');
        foreach($last_id_insert as $result)
        {
          $id_last_inserted = $result->id;
        }

        foreach($file_upload as $value)
        {


            $name=$value->hashName();

            $value->move(public_path().'/storage/',$name);

            DB::insert('INSERT INTO content_files (content_id,file_name) VALUES (?,?) ',[

                 $id_last_inserted,
                 $name,



            ]);
        }

        return response()->json('Success');
    }
    else {

        DB::insert('INSERT INTO content (content_author,content_title,content_desc,content_link,content_page,content_status,when_created) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ',[

        $author,
        $carousel_title,
        $carousel_desc,
        $carousel_url,
        'carousel',
        'Approved',
        $now

        ]);

         return response()->json('Success');
    }

}
```

**Img Src:**

[image: img source]

**User Display:**

[image: user display]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the images are stored into the database successfully, but the issue may be that your storage path doesn't have the right access rights. (Chmod 755)

To specify that simply write in ssh `sudo chmod -R 755 storage/`

From your post I can see that image_name is stored onto the database table, but image is not stored on your server.

To display images from Storage you should use : `Storage::get('file_name.jpg');`

You can see that here : https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#retrieving-files

Comment: still same. even 755 chmod set

Comment: You can try to set for testing purposes now the sudo -R chmod 777 storage/ if it doesn't help can you please view in inspect element the image src and show it here? (without the domain of course)

Comment: sure.. i will post the image src.

Comment: Also please show me how do you display the images in the carusel (public users)

Comment: And how you are displaying the images to the public side?

Comment: using the asset. <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="{{asset('/public/storage/'.$carousel_data->file_name)}}">

Comment: Can you try to use `Storage::get($carousel_data->file_name); ` ? and take a look in inspect to the link if it's not working. Don't for get `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;`

Comment: And if it's not working please show me your app/filesystems.php content

Comment: i used this . 'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

Comment: Storage::get() is not working as well? That is the way how in laravel you can get files from the storage. Also - by default laravel uses local filesystem driver.

Comment: it not works. i don't know why. this is the first time i experience this. all  my project that i deploy fine.

Comment: and locally its working as it should? There is something you have forgotten to do. 1.) Setup chmod 777 to storage path;
2.) run  php artisan storage:link
3.) Check if the file actually exists (maybe you forgot to push the local files to prod.)
4.) try to upload new files and inspect them. But validate that the file paths are 1000% correct!

Comment: Hi Frank i found out the problem, it happens when the name of file that I upload is not unique and then the file name exist is same to the file that I upload it automatically inserting duplicate..